# Adding JS and CSS webresource to use in velocity template doesn't work in JIRA 6.4

Tags: jira-plugin

Our JIRA project tab panel plugin was working fine with with external web resources (JS & CSS) until 6.3.9, after migrating to 6.4 they're no longer included in the velocity templates. How can we solve this problem? Has there been a change in the way web resources are included in velocity templates? Please help.

```
<web-resource key="project-tab-resources" name="project-tab Web Resources">
  <resource type="download" name="project-tab.css" location="/css/project-tab.css"/>
  <resource type="download" name="project-tab.js" location="/js/project-tab.js"/>
```

project-tab

Comment: Which resources? How are you declaring your web resources in the plugin descriptor?

Comment: We have a project-tab-panel and we need to include our css and our js. 
They are declared in the atlassian-plugin.xml as usual and until 6.3.9 everything were been included correctly.
We have tried changing the context (from specific to atl-general) but id didn't worked.

Comment: I've edited teh question with contents of plugin-descriptor. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution:

We are running a local instance of Jira via `atlas-debug` to be able to reload frontend changes without recompiling.
The right way to do the upgrade is:

- change the `jira-version` in `pom.xml`.
- **Before** running `atlas-debug` run `mvn clean`
- run `atlas-debug` as usual

Be careful with `mvn clean` because if you are using an *in memory* database it will be destroyed